# Здания и сооружения

Tags: синонимы

Часто эти два слова употребляются рядом: "здания и сооружения". А разве это не одно и то же? Или же все-таки всякое здание - сооружение, но не всякое сооружение - здание?
Спасибо

Comment: По моему мнению, мавзолей на Красной площади в Москве - сооружение, но не здание.

Comment: @Галактион! Там же человек лежит, хотя и покойный! Почему же это сооружение?! Сооружение - это Эйфелева башня,Колизей,бомбоубежище, Волгоградская ГЭС, помещение (с окнами или без оных) для сторожей на кладбище и проч. Здание Верховного Совета СССР и т. п. - нежилые, но здания.

Comment: По моим сведениям, в мавзолее на Красной площади в Москве находится труп  "вождя мирового пролетариата" В. И. Ульянова (Ленина). По моему мнению, этот труп следует передать в антропологический музей в Санкт-Петербурге (быв.  Ленинграде).

Comment: Ну, знаете, это как решит народ. Лично мне он не мешает: я далеко от Москвы, как назвал сво

Comment: свой роман Василий Ажаев, за который он получил, помнится, Сталинскую премию 3 - й степени. Я читал его, но в памяти ничего не осталось: было это так давно, что не верится, что сам читал его. Впрочем, к Владимиру Ильичу это никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: Какой "народ" должен определить местоположение трупа единственного "вождя мирового пролетариата"? "Мировой пролетариат"? "Трудящийся и эксплуатируемый народ"? "Советский народ"? "Многонациональный народ Российской Федерации"?

Comment: Конечно,все мы, современные люди с учётом заинтересованных мнений коммунистов прочих стран

Comment: Стало быть, местоположение трупа единственного "вождя мирового пролетариата" должен определить "народ", который называется "современные люди с учётом заинтересованных мнений коммунистов прочих стран".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос следует окунуться  в область, где эти два понятия употребляются  чаще всего: регистрация и инвентаризация недвижимости. Вот выдержка из инструкции «о порядке проведения технической инвентаризации недвижимого имущества»:
«Здание – строительная система, состоящая (по мере необходимости) из наземной и подземной частей, с помещениями для проживания и (или) деятельности людей, размещения производства, хранения продукции или содержании животных».
Сооружение – объёмная, плоскостная или линейная наземная, подземная или надземная строительная система, прочно связанная с землёй, состоящая из несущих, а в отдельных случаях и ограждающих конструкций и предназначенных для производственных процессов различного вида, хранения материалов, изделий оборудования, для временного пребывания людей, грузов и так далее.( в ред. Постановления Госкомимущества от 20.12.2010№75)
Из чего следует, что **здание – это, безусловно, сооружение, но с помещениями,** куда можно что-то (кого-то) помещать. Сооружения – это и дороги, и столбы с проводами, и ямы для хранения корма скоту, и детские песочницы. Естественно, к зданиям подобные конструкции не имеют никакого отношения, ибо в них нет помещений.

Answer (score 2):

Такие вопросы обычно можно решить с помощью словаря:

ЗДАНИЕ, Архитектурное сооружение, постройка (обычно больших размеров). Строить, ремонтировать з. З. университета, больницы. З. из стекла и бетона. З. с колоннами. Административное з. Историческое з.

СООРУЖЕНИЕ, То, что сооружено; постройка, строение (различного вида и назначение, обычно сложное по устройству). Оборонительные, гидротехнические, ирригационные сооружения. Многоэтажные железобетонные сооружения современных городов.

Из этого следует, что здание - это особое (архитектурное) сооружение, то есть частный вид сооружения - таким образом, из всех сооружений мы особо выделяем здания и пишем: здания и (остальные) сооружения.

Получается, что "всякое здание - сооружение, но не всякое сооружение - здание".